# Как обойти ограничения backgroundFetch при отправке данных в фоновом режиме?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple, sdk

Необходимо осуществить передачу данных iOS приложением на сервер в тот момент, когда приложение находится в фоновом режиме. Данные представляют собой небольшие объёмы данных о статусах устройства пользователя (связано с технологией iBeacon и местоположением пользователя). Данные необходимо отправлять раз в полчаса/час. При этом само приложение может находиться в бэкграунд режиме довольно долго (несколько дней), из-за чего возникает проблема с ограничениями backgroundFetch.

Есть ли какие либо решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Возможен вариант с `Push Notifications`. Они заставляют приложение проснуться на какое-то время, даже если приложение не активно, в этот момент можно отправить запрос на сервер. Но пользователь тогда должен разрешить приложению работу с `push`, иначе вся эта затея будет напрасной.